# Print JSON string from URL

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm using ajax to parse JSON data from a URL. I need to capture the parsed array into a variable. How would I go about this? Thanks

```
function rvOffices() {
$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/roivantsciences/offices',
    type:'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function( data) {
        // get string
    }
});
}
rvOffices();
var rvOfficesString = // resultant string
```

Comment: you can use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ so you need  var data = $.parseJSON(jsonData)...

Comment: you're saying use that rather than an ajax call?

Comment: nope assuming everything works ok with your setup in success to get the data returned use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse(data)` to convert the desired output to JSON, and then access the objects and array indexes from within that with `.object` and `[array_index]` respectively:

```js
function rvOffices() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/roivantsciences/offices',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      var json_result = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log(json_result); // The whole JSON
      console.log(json_result.offices[0].name);
    }
  });
}
rvOffices();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You also don't need to pass any `data`, as you're performing a `GET` request.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks that does help!

Answer (score 1):

So I guess you are not sure about the ajax call, so lets break it..

1. Ajax call is a simply method to make a request to remote resource (Get/post/put...) the type of request (GET/POST) depends upon your need.
2. so if you have an endpoint that return simply data as in your case a simple get/post request is sufficient.
3. You can send addition data with request to get the data from endpoint (say id of resource (say person) whose other fields you want to get like name, age, address).
4. here is *[link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)* for ajax request in jQuery
5. here is *[jQuery parse json](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)*  parse json in jQuery

So for example:

```js
// let's say when you call this function it will make post request to fixed end point and return data else null

function rvOffices() {
var res = null; // let be default null
$.ajax({
url:'https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/roivantsciences/offices',
type:'GET', // type of request method
dataType: 'text', // type of data you want to send if any.
success: function( data) {
   res = $.parseJSON(data); // will do the parsing of data returned if ajax succeeds (assuming your endpoint will return JSON data.)
}
});
return res;
}

// lets call the function 
var rvOfficesString = rvOffices();

// print the value returned 
console.log(rvOfficesString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like: -

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/roivantsciences/offices',
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(response) {
    // get string
       window.temp = JSON.parse(response);
    }
});
```